# Appx Package without install location

Tags: windows-10, powershell, package-management, windows-store

Recently I encountered some HD issues and I was forced to replace the affected drive.
Unfortunately, several Microsoft store apps were stored on this very drive.

I wanted to reinstall the affected apps, only to find out that they were still listed as installed. Running the `Get-AppxPackage` in elevated PS, I found that all packages are still present, with their InstallLocation entries empty.

For example:

```
Name                   : PrivateDivision.TheOuterWorldsWindows10
Publisher              : CN=9018231E-16CC-4B64-9C06-FBDF538FCE92
Architecture           : X64
ResourceId             :
Version                : 1.4.617.0
PackageFullName        : PrivateDivision.TheOuterWorldsWindows10_1.4.617.0_x64__hv3d7yfbgr2rp
InstallLocation        :
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : PrivateDivision.TheOuterWorldsWindows10_hv3d7yfbgr2rp
PublisherId            : hv3d7yfbgr2rp
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-18 [S-1-5-18]: Paused}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
NonRemovable           : False
Dependencies           : {Microsoft.DirectXRuntime_9.29.952.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe, Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.29231.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged      : False
SignatureKind          : Store
Status                 : Ok
```

When I tried to remove them using Remove-AppxPackage command, I only encountered further exceptions.
The full log didn't provide much in a way of help, and neither did the linked Microsoft pages.

```
Time                      ID           Message
----                      --           -------
10/28/2020 11:34:09 AM    603          Started deployment Remove operation on a package with main parameter PrivateDivision.TheOuterWorldsWindows10_1.4.617.0_x64__hv3d7yfbgr2rp and Options 0 and 0. See
                                       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
10/28/2020 11:34:09 AM    10002        Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\d12701d1-7670-4331-a98a-f65b7153543d_S-1-5-21-1646043629-652804291-2581767941-1001_153.rslc for Remove
                                       Operation on Package PrivateDivision.TheOuterWorldsWindows10_1.4.617.0_x64__hv3d7yfbgr2rp.
10/28/2020 11:34:09 AM    607          Deployment Remove operation on package PrivateDivision.TheOuterWorldsWindows10_1.4.617.0_x64__hv3d7yfbgr2rp has been de-queued and is running for user SID
                                       S-1-5-21-1646043629-652804291-2581767941-1001.
10/28/2020 11:34:09 AM    605          The last successful state reached was BundleProcessed. Failure occurred before reaching the next state Indexed. hr: 0x80070002
10/28/2020 11:34:09 AM    401          Deployment DeStage operation with target volume C: on Package PrivateDivision.TheOuterWorldsWindows10_1.4.617.0_x64__hv3d7yfbgr2rp from:   failed with error 0x80070002. See
                                       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
10/28/2020 11:34:09 AM    404          AppX Deployment operation failed for package PrivateDivision.TheOuterWorldsWindows10_1.4.617.0_x64__hv3d7yfbgr2rp with error 0x80073CFA. The specific error text for this failure is:
                                       Deployment DeStage operation with target volume C: on Package PrivateDivision.TheOuterWorldsWindows10_1.4.617.0_x64__hv3d7yfbgr2rp from:   failed with error 0x80070002. See
                                       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues
```

I did try to reset the store, using both `wsreset.exe` and Settings app, and after rebooting the system I  found one of the apps was no longer showing as installed. However, my attempts to install it failed, with exception `0x80073CF9`. And the app is still listed in output of `Get-AppxPackage`.

I can only summarize that the issue stems from app not being correctly removed in the first place.
But since can't uninstall them using either the Store, Add and Remove programs aps, or powershell commands, I am at loss at what to do.

My latest restore point is before I replaced the drive.

But it didn't help. No surprise there, since I didn't set it up on affected drive.

EDIT:
For the record. I did attempt solutions presented in: [Error 0x80073cf9 when installing or updating apps from windows store](https://superuser.com/questions/489663/error-0x80073cf9-when-installing-or-updating-apps-from-windows-store) With no effect.

So this question is neither duplicate, nor already answered.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of this one as it has the same error codes you've noted: https://superuser.com/questions/1115801/unable-to-uninstall-universal-apps-through-powershell